# Should I tell my recruiter that I applied for another position at the same company?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I have an interview coming up and I also applied for a different job in the same company in a different location. Should I tell my recruiter that I applied to another position in the same company?

Comment: Is this recruiter someone that works for the company, or are they a third-party recruiter that set you up with the company?

Comment: Works for the company, I think-email has the company

Answer (score 3):

> Should you tell your recruiter that you applied another position in the same company?

### Yes

You don't want to be represented by two different recruiters for jobs at the same company at the same time.
That  conflict **can cause you to be dropped from consideration of *both* positions**.
If you applied to one position and recruiter applied you to another, you can still trigger this problem.

Answer assumes that the recruiter is "external" to the company that you would be working for (full time or contract) - if s/he is internal I would still mention it.

Answer (score 1):

For sure. But it’s likely that they already know, because companies usually have a central HR dept.

Comment: This answer works if it is an internal recruiter who works for HR and only recruits for their own company. The recruiter in OP's question could be external to the company, in which case they'd have no visibility.